# Bar Color In Chart JS

Tags: jquery, json, joomla, chart.js, chart.js2

I am returning one dataset from one query in php and storing in a JSON array.  The format of my JSON array is like such

```
Bein, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 .......
```

I am using the below syntax to store into an array, pass to JSON and create my Chart.JS  The issue I have is that I want all of the data points for 13 to be one color and all the data points for 14 to be a different color.  The two months need to remain side by side.  Does Chart.js have a function/feature that can accomodate for this?

```
<?php
    $rows = $db->loadRowList();
    $output = array(); 
    foreach( $rows as $row ) { 
    array_push($output, $row); } 
    $data = json_encode($output[0]);
?>

<script>
    "use strict";
    var jsondata = <?php echo $data; ?>;;
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
        values.push(jsondata[i]);
    }
    var labelsarr = ["Jan 13", "Jan 14", "Feb 13", "Feb 14", "Mar 13", "Mar 14", "Apr 13", "Apr 14", "May 13", "May 14", "Jun 13", "Jun 14", "Jul 13", "Jul 14", "Aug 13", "Aug 14", "Sep 13", "Sep 14", "Oct 13", "Oct 14", "Nov 13", "Nov 14", "Dec 13", "Dec 14"];
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labelsarr,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Test',
                data: values,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(t, d) {
                        var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                        var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
                        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: '<?php echo $name ?> 2013 & 2014 Data'
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            } else {
                                return '$' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this at the moment. You would rather need to create a chart plugin to accomplish that ...

```
plugins: [{
   beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var labels = chart.data.labels;
      labels.forEach(function(e, i) {
         var bar = chart.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[i]._model;
         var dataPoint = e.split(/\s/)[1];
         if (dataPoint === '13') bar.backgroundColor = 'red';
         else if (dataPoint === '14') bar.backgroundColor = 'green';
      });
   }
}]
```

<sup>add this followed by your chart options</sup>

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
var jsondata = ['Bein', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];
var values = [];
for (var i = 1; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
   values.push(jsondata[i]);
}
var labelsarr = ["Jan 13", "Jan 14", "Feb 13", "Feb 14", "Mar 13", "Mar 14", "Apr 13", "Apr 14", "May 13", "May 14", "Jun 13", "Jun 14", "Jul 13", "Jul 14", "Aug 13", "Aug 14", "Sep 13", "Sep 14", "Oct 13", "Oct 14", "Nov 13", "Nov 14", "Dec 13", "Dec 14"];

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: labelsarr,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Test',
         data: values,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.8)',
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
               var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
               return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
            }
         }
      },
      legend: {
         position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
         display: true,
         text: 'Year 2013 Total Revenue By Month'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                     return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                  } else {
                     return '$' + value;
                  }
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
         var labels = chart.data.labels;
         labels.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var bar = chart.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[i]._model;
            var dataPoint = e.split(/\s/)[1];
            if (dataPoint === '13') bar.backgroundColor = 'red';
            else if (dataPoint === '14') bar.backgroundColor = 'green';
         });
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the DataSet label?  I tried to omit this line - but now it just shows as undefined. label: 'Test',  Or possibly set a DataSet label for both the green and red color to distinguish when  you hover?

Comment: Yes, set `display: false` for legend.